# How to bring the json structure to linear time complexity?

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm, time-complexity, reduce

Input json:

```
const i = {
  "38931": [{
      "userT": "z",
      "personId": 13424,
      "user": {
        "id": 38931,
        "email": "sample",
      },
    },
    {
      "userType": "z",
      "personId": 19999,
      "user": {
        "id": 38931,
        "email": "sample",
      },
    }
  ],
  "77777": [{
    "userT": "z",
    "personId": 55555,
    "user": {
      "id": 77777,
      "email": "sample",
    },
  }]
}
```

desired output

```
{
  "38931": {
    "13424": {
      "userT": "z",
      "personId": 13424,
      "user": {
        "id": 38931,
        "email": "sample"
      }
    },
    "19999": {
      "userType": "z",
      "personId": 19999,
      "user": {
        "id": 38931,
        "email": "sample"
      }
    }
  },
  "77777": {
    "55555": {
      "userT": "z",
      "personId": 55555,
      "user": {
        "id": 77777,
        "email": "sample"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I tried to bring it to `O(n)`, but still the destructuring in the reducer will give me O(n2) which is in the last `.reducer` func with callback `accObject`.

```js
const i = {
  "38931": [{
      "userT": "z",
      "personId": 13424,
      "user": {
        "id": 38931,
        "email": "sample",
      },
    },
    {
      "userType": "z",
      "personId": 19999,
      "user": {
        "id": 38931,
        "email": "sample",
      },
    }
  ],
  "77777": [{
    "userT": "z",
    "personId": 55555,
    "user": {
      "id": 77777,
      "email": "sample",
    },
  }]
}


const accList = (acc, id) => {
  acc.push(i[id]);
  return acc;
}
const accObject = (acc, [key, val]) => {
  const {
    user: {
      id
    }
  } = val;
  acc[id] = {
    ...acc[id],
    [key]: val
  };
  return acc;
}

// concat arrays of main object (i) 2D array, transform to 1D array, 
// transform to hashMap with key personId,
// transform to array for iterable (Object.entries) and create the object result.

const personas = Object.keys(i)
  .reduce(accList, [])
  .flat()
  .reduce((acc, obj) => {
    acc[obj.personId] = obj;
    return acc;
  }, {});

const result =
  Object
  .entries(personas)
  .reduce(accObject, {});

console.log('result', result);
```

It does give me the correct result, but am wondering if there is a bette approach to have

`T = O(n)`

Comment: if you need an optimized result, just use Recursion instead.

Comment: recursion doesnt make much sense here. the depth is final.

Comment: @sohaiebazaiez: moreover the key being used is different at every level.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do this with a single iteration over the entries in the top-level object, converting the array of objects under each key into an object using `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const i = {
  "38931": [{
      "userT": "z",
      "personId": 13424,
      "user": {
        "id": 38931,
        "email": "sample",
      },
    },
    {
      "userType": "z",
      "personId": 19999,
      "user": {
        "id": 38931,
        "email": "sample",
      },
    }
  ],
  "77777": [{
    "userT": "z",
    "personId": 55555,
    "user": {
      "id": 77777,
      "email": "sample",
    },
  }]
}

const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(i)
  .map(([k, v]) => [k,
    Object.fromEntries(v.map(o => [o.personId, o]))
  ])
)

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top 0; }
```

If you don't mind modifying the object in place, you can use a simple `forEach`:

```js
const i = {
  "38931": [{
      "userT": "z",
      "personId": 13424,
      "user": {
        "id": 38931,
        "email": "sample",
      },
    },
    {
      "userType": "z",
      "personId": 19999,
      "user": {
        "id": 38931,
        "email": "sample",
      },
    }
  ],
  "77777": [{
    "userT": "z",
    "personId": 55555,
    "user": {
      "id": 77777,
      "email": "sample",
    },
  }]
}

Object.keys(i).forEach(k => i[k] = Object.fromEntries(i[k].map(o => [o.personId, o])))

console.log(i)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top 0; }
```

Comment: but that is On2 complexity what you just did

Comment: @EugenSunic see my edit for a modify-in-place which is O(n)

Comment: aaah, yea I would prefer not to mutate but nice in place solution

Comment: I have to go to a meeting but curious to compare why you think my other solution is O(n^2), because the nested map only iterates the values of the individual entries in the object. So it becomes 1x2 + 1x1 for your sample data

Comment: Well for the first not in place solution you have the first .map which can have n elements and then for every element there can be m elements in the list. hence it's  O(m x n ) to be more precise.

Comment: This is linear in the total number of innermost elements (your `m * n`), and since you need all that data, you cannot do better.  Perhaps another technique would improve the coefficients, but not the algorithmic complexity.

Comment: @ScottSauyet m x n is not linear, mathematically it's called multilinear, neither m nor n is constant. When you say total number of inner elements is linear not sure what you mean since this is not the case.

Comment: @EugenSunic consider the case where there are `i` top-level arrays, and each array has `j` user objects in it, so the total number of user objects is `n = i*j`. The total number of operations is `i` (for the outer-level map) and `i*j` (for the inner-level map) i.e. `i+i*j == i + n` so that makes it O(n)